# Calculate employees required using ratio

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ratio

I am doing a school assignment to calculate the number of employees required to complete a construction contract.

$3$ workers take $1.5$ hours to complete $5000$ units of work. If there are  $437,400$ units of work, and only $128$ hours to complete it, how many employees will you need?

**Update**

Ok I had a go at solving this using the [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication#Rule_of_three).

```
it takes 3 workers 1.5 hours to create 5K
it takes X workers 128 hours to create 437.4k

5K/1.5/3 = 437.4K/128/X

=> X = (437.4K * 1.5 * 3)/(5K*128)

=> 3
```

Was this the correct solution?

Comment: "He thought he saw a Garden-Door / That opened with a key: / He looked again, and found it was / [A double rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication#Double_rule_of_three)" *Lewis Carroll*

Comment: Use reason: if 3 works 1.5 hours to produce 5, then 1 will work 1.5 hours to produce $\dfrac 5 3$. Then 1 in 1 hour will produce $\dfrac { \dfrac 5 3 }{1.5}$

Comment: Thanks guys this should be enough of a hint to solve

Comment: I've updated with my work. Do you all agree with the result? @Mauro ALLEGRANZA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$3$ workers taking $1.5$ hours (so $4.5$ worker-hours) to complete $5000$ units of work means $\frac{5000}{4.5} \approx 1111.1111$ units of work per worker hour.

$437,400$ units of work would then take about $\frac{437400}{1111.1111}\approx 393.66$ worker-hours, i.e. about $\frac{393.66}{128}\approx 3.075$ workers in $128$ hours.

You have rounded this to $3$.  But that is not exactly correct: $3$ workers would do about $426,666.67$ units of work in $128$ hours, which is not quite enough; a $4$th work needs to do $9.66$ hours work to make up the difference.